# deleting blank lines after loop

Tags: ruby

ok, I have the following, very simple code:

```
f = "String1\n\n\nString2\n\n\n"
f.each_line do |t|
  t.delete! "\n"
  puts t.inspect
end
```

It removes the \n, but leaves the spaces

```
"String1"
nil
nil
"String2"
nil
nil
```

I want it to look like this:

```
"String1"
"String2"
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't leave any spaces. It returns an empty string. What result are you looking for?

Comment: Are you sure the exact code you have produces `nil` in the output, rather than `""`? It shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f.squeeze("\n").each_line do |l|
  puts l
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803) the string by `\n`, and then [reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002196) any blank lines:

```
f = "String1\n\n\nString2\n\n\n"
f.split("\n").reject { |i| i.empty? }
#=> ["String1", "String2"]
```

You'd end up with an Array that you can output as you'd like.

Comment: can you split the string by nil?

Answer (score 1):

```
f = "String1\n\n\nString2\n\n\n"
f.each_line.collect(&:chomp).reject(&:empty?)
#=> ["String1", "String2"]
```

The `collect(&:chomp)` removes line endings.  `reject(&:empty?)` throws away all of the empty lines.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely have use for your input.