# Eliminating nil lines

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
f = File.open("/log/mytext.txt")
f.each_line do |i|
i = i.delete("\n")
puts i.inspect
```

The delete gets rid of the \n, but the result looks like this:

```
"#<MatchData \"line1\">"
""
""
""
"#<MatchData \"line2\">"
```

Want it to return :

```
line1
line2
```

Been fighting this problem all day. Thanks for your help

Comment: This same question was asked almost word-for-word about two hours ago. Hasn't anyone ever heard of Google?

Comment: What is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773853 You can edit your previous question, if you want. No need to make duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [deleting blank lines after loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773853/deleting-blank-lines-after-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p File.open("/log/mytext.txt").each_line.map(&:rstrip).delete_if(&:empty?)
```

And now let me explain :)

1. `p expr` is equivalent to `puts expr.inspect`, which will show the result.
2. `rstrip` is a simpler way to remove the trailing newlines (and any trailing spaces).
3. `delete_if(&:empty?)`, which is equivalent to `delete_if{|x| x.empty?}` checks to see if the strings are blank, and doesn't let them through if so.